# Test a class with Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, sessionfactory

I defined the following class:

```
public class ArticleMagasinDAOImpl implements ArticleMagasinDAO {
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        public Article findArticleByName(String name){
            Article article = null;
                try {
                    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                    Query q = session.createQuery("from Article c where c.name='"+ name+"'");
                    article = (Article) q.uniqueResult();   
                    return article;     
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //logger.error(e.getMessage()) ;
                }
                return article;

            }
    }
```

How can I test it?

Comment: You need to write a JUnit test case, your test case should create the data, test and destroy the data. It is better if you can configure different database (in memory databases work well here) for test cases.

Comment: shameless plug: http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/